# jquery position function for inner(nested) li returns zero

Tags: jquery, position, zero

I have nested li, which is for horizontal subnav menu. I am trying to get the position of li of child li using jquery's position() function but it is returning zero always. Same function is working for parent li.

Html Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu_style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script>
            $(window).load(function() {
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery('.addchar').live('click', function(event) {
                        var position = $(this).position();
                        alert(position.left);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="menu" id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="addchar">A</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" class="addchar">Aword</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="addchar">B</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" class="addchar">Bword </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
.menu{
    border:none;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position:relative;/*should be relative*/
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu ul{
    background:#333333;
    height:40px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:900px;
}

.menu li{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    width:28px;
    font-size:16px;
}
.menu li a{
    background:#333333 url("../img/seperator.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#cccccc;
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:35px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 12px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover a{
    background: #2580a2 url("../img/hover.gif") bottom center no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li ul{
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:900px;
    float:right;
    z-index:200;
}
.menu li:hover ul{
    display:block;

}
.menu li li {
    background:url('../img/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:36px;
}
.menu li:hover li a{
    background:none;

}
.menu li ul a{
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
}
.menu li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a{
    background:#2580a2 url('../img/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
    border:0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean position in terms of pixels? [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) gives you the position *relative to the offset parent*. As each of your menu links is the only child of the parent, the return value will always be zero (if you don't do some fancy positioning).

You might want [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), which gives you the position relative to the document.

If you want to get the *index* of the menu item in the set of all menu items, then you need to use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$('#menu ul ul .addchar').index(this);
```

Comment: Although there were multiple child(in non stripped html) I was just checking the first child and now after you mentioned it other than first child returning position value properly. Thanks